# Is it possible to get an extended facebook accessToken using an expired token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have a native app which utilises facebook as a login method. I am currently following the `Login on Client, API Calls from Server` token flow (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/portability/). This means that my backend stores the extended access token & makes the FB calls on behalf of the client.

I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to EXTEND an EXTENDED ACCESS TOKEN (lasts 4 60 days). Why would I want todo this? If one of my users doesn't use the application within 60 days, then the stored extended access token EXPIRES and the user won't be able to interact with anything that requires the fb access token.

- Can I extend an exprired 'extended access token'?
- Can I somehow get a refreshToken with the extended token response? (so that when the extendedToken expires, I can use the refreshToken to generate a new extendedToken)
- Do I have to ask the user to connect with facebook again? (worst case)

Comment: Or course you can not. If you could there would be no reason to expire them. Yes just pop the Facebook Login dialog again

Comment: @WizKid Do you know if you can get a refresh access token when you get an extended access token?

Comment: Don't know what you mean

Comment: FB.getLoginStatus can do that for you. of course only if the user hits your app/website.